# Does measurement error include effects of moderator variables?

Tags: interaction, meta-analysis, bias, measurement-error

I am not very sure how to interpret measurement error correctly: as a constant, as a bias, or as a moderator factor? Is it presumed that measurement error includes moderator effects?   Let it be in the context of meta-analysis of effect sizes.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the edit. I think moderator factors cause a constant bias, But this should not imply that measurement error is equivalent to the effect(s) of a moderator(s). Is it right thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that it might depend on what is being measured:

- If you are estimating a latent variable with several measured variables, one might think of measurement variance as moderation of the relationships between measurements and the latent factor due to other variables (e.g., gender, SES, nationality).
- If you are measuring a variable directly (e.g., blood pressure, skin conductance, seismic activity), you might think of other variables moderating your measurement error, but I find a distinction between measurement error and moderator effects useful in that context.
- If you are estimating a relationship between variables (e.g., correlation, slope coefficent, group differences), then the standard error of your estimate will probably be larger if you fail to control for a moderator variable. I'm not sure it's wise to conflate standard errors of estimates with measurement error, but I'm not sure it's incorrect either...it just might be confusing.

I would probably prefer that an author give all these matters their own terminology rather than lumping it all together under measurement error. However, if the question is one of interpreting someone else's unclear usage, I'm afraid there are ways one could decide to call moderator effects "measurement error" in all three of these cases, and maybe others too. Measurement error ought to entail more than just moderator effects in any case though, so yes, the two are not equivalent.

Comment: thanks for the response and I accept your verdict, would you please define and explain the term "conflate". Are you going up or down along the moderator

Comment: @Stauner can I have your email address.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster has an example most similar to my usage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflate): "to combine (as two readings of a text) into a composite whole.
Examples of CONFLATE: <be careful not to conflate gossip with real news>" Are you looking for a statistical consultant?

Comment: please explain the term in simple wordings.

Comment: Again, I refer you to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/).